# SRAtoolkit: error while running prefetch: path not found while resolving tree within virtual file system module

Tags: sequence, bioinformatics, dna-sequence, fastq, ncbi

I have been using a Unix shell to download raw reads using sratoolkit/2.8.2-1. The SRA files are from the NCBI database e.g. for "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra?term=SRX1157907". When I use the prefetch command (e.g. prefetch SRR2172947) consistently get the error of "path not found while resolving tree within virtual file system module - 'SRR2172948' cannot be found." I can download other SRA files like SRR12626663 without a problem, but the mentioned link has some problem.

Would it be possible to please guide me on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Human genomics data in NCBI's SRA is often under controlled access through [the dbGaP system](https://dbgap.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/aa/wga.cgi?page=login). One must request access to these files and follow special protocols to download such data. For example, researchers must demonstrate valid research needs to gain access approval and agree to follow protocols to ensure the data is securely stored.

[image]